# How to get scrollbar in eclipse default tooltip?

Tags: eclipse, tooltip, rcp

I have a custom tooltip class which extends ColumnViewerToolTipSupport and overrides createViewerToolTipContentArea().
Still I do not see the scrollbar upon mouse click within the tooltip.

How to get the scrollbar added ? Is this possible ?
How to make tooltip function exactly like eclipse tooptip?

[image: Tooltip Scrollbar image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. If you are creating the tool tip use a `ScrolledComposite` to get scrolling. When you click inside a tooltip in something like the Java editor the tooltip is actually closed and a new shell of exactly the same size replaces it - ColumnViewerToolTipSupport doesn't have any code for that.

Comment: Please refer the image link added in description. I need to add scrollbar similar to one which eclipse gives upon hovering on a method name in editor.

Comment: Use a `ScrolledComposite` when you create the controls in `createViewerToolTipContentArea`.